# Directly showing $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\zeta (k+2) =1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3778142) it is shown, up to a small detail or two, that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{1}{m}\Big)^n\cdot \frac{1}{m^2}=1$$
The proof essentially involves Taylor series and reimagining the sum as a Riemann integral to show a lower bound and an upper bound each converge to $1$.

However, I believe the problem can be solved a different way. If we use the binomial theorem to expand $(1-1/m)^n$ and swap the resulting double sum, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\zeta (k+2)
$$Intuitively, this limit should converge because $\zeta(n+2)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, and then the series looks like $\sum_{0\le k\le n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k=0$, but the asymptotics evade me. Previously I was interested in so-called 'alternating binomial zeta series,' (my own clunky descriptor of this object) and found that convergence was quite delicate and subtle. I tried using Stolz-Cesaro, the discrete version of L'Hopital's Rule, but was unsusccessful, though maybe it's possible through this or other means.

Comment: The problem is that the $\binom{n}{k}$ terms get bigger and bigger as $n\to\infty,$ so this seems harder, not easier, than the original series. You are essentially hiding the cancellation. But you could write it as $$n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk(-1)^{k}(\zeta(k+2)-1)$$  We have that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\zeta(k+2)-1)=1,$ so $\zeta(k+2)-1$ seems more useful here than $\zeta(k+2).$ It is a probability measure on $\mathbb N.$

Comment: Those are excellent points, Thomas! I will try to think about them and report back.

Answer (score 1):

A proof of the asymptotics for
$$ H_{\nu}(x) := \sum_{k>\text{Re}\,\nu+1} (-1)^k\binom{x}{k} \zeta(n-\nu) $$
appears in the publication 'On Mellin-Barnes Type of Integrals and Sums Associated with the Riemann Zeta-Function,' by M. Katsurada, in *Public. de L'Institut Mathematique* Nouvell serie, tome 62, (76) 1997, 13-25.

Theorem 4.1 states that, for $\nu$ not in the set {-1, 0, 1, 2, ...}
$$H_{\nu}(x)  = \frac{\Gamma(1+x)\,\Gamma(-v-1)}{\Gamma(x-\nu)} - \sum_{k=0}^{[\text{Re}\,\nu+1]} (-1)^k\binom{x}{k} \zeta(n-\nu) + \cal{R}_\nu(x)$$

The proposer's question is for $\nu = -2.$  The empty sum contributes nothing,
and
$$H_{-2}(x)= \frac{1}{1+x} + \cal{R}_{-2}(x) $$
Corollary 4.1 bounds the error as *exponentially small*
$$\cal{R}_{-2}(x) = \cal{O}\big(x^{1/2} \exp{(-D\,x^{1/3})}\big) \, , D=4.5201... $$
The proof requires some sophistication in complex analysis and some knowledge of special function theory.  I tried to solve this problem on my own, even using special function theory, and got to a place where I had to regularize some integrals.  The first term (1/x) worked with out regularization, and the rest of my terms all went to zero.  That occurrence told me that it was likely that the error was exponentially small, (that is, the asymptotic series won't contain $x^{-3/2}, x^{-2}...$) and Katsurada's paper proves it.

Comment: I will check out the paper you suggested, thanks! All things being equal, I'd be fine awarding the bounty to this answer.

Comment: How would you find an exact expression for the error term? Showing that's exponential small is ofcourse a good start, but less satisfying. Could you please share the integral you found (and how) for the error term?

Comment: @Gerben The integral I found does not give an explicit exponentially small term, but only suggests it.  It does show the 1/x asymptotic term.  Trying to go further, and all the terms for $x^{-3/2}$, $x^{-2}$ equate to zero.  That kind of analysis just doesn't quantify the exponentially small term.  I also think it's somewhat interesting, and maybe it should be asked as another question.  The paper I give a reference to does answer the OP's question, and with an error bound.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an interesting formula.

Let $p_j=\zeta(j)-1$ for $j>1.$

Let: $$A_{n,i}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom nk p_{k+i},$$ for $i>1,$ then we get $$\begin{align}A_{n+1,i}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^k\left(\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}
\right)p_{k+i}\\&=A_{n,i} -A_{n,i+1}\tag{1}\end{align}$$

So if $B_{n,i}=(n+i)A_{n,i},$ then $$B_{n+1,i}=\left(B_{n,i}-B_{n,i+1}\right) + A_{n,i}$$

Now you are trying to prove $B_{n,2}\to 1.$ (Technically, you want $\frac{n}{n+2}B_{n,2}\to 1,$ but that is the same thing.)

Substituting again, we get:

$$\begin{align}B_{n+2,i}&=\left(\left(B_{n,i}-B_{n,i+1}\right)+A_{n,i}\right)-\left((B_{n,i+1}-B_{n,i+2})+A_{n,i+1}\right)+A_{n+1,i}\\
&=\left(B_{n,i}-2B_{n,i+1}+B_{n,i+2}\right)+A_{n,i}+A_{n+1,i}-A_{n,i+1}\\
&=2A_{n+1,i}
\end{align}$$ The last step by (1).

Inductively you'll get:

$$B_{n+m,i}=\sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^m \binom{m}{j}B_{n,i+j}+mA_{n+m-1,i}
$$

Using $B_{1,i}=A_{1,i}=p_{i}-p_{i+1},$ we get:
$$B_{n,2}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{j}\binom{n-1}{j}(p_{2+j}-p_{3+j}) +B_{n-1,2}$$

So: $$\begin{align}B_{n,2}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j}\binom{k}{j}(p_{2+j}-p_{3+j})\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^j(p_{2+j}-p_{3+j})\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}\binom{k}{j}\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j+1}(p_{2+j}-p_{3+j})\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{j}\binom n{j+1}p_{2+j}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j}\binom n{j}p_{2+j}\\
&=np_{2}+(-1)^np_{2+n}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{j}\left(\binom n{j+1}+\binom nj\right)p_{2+j}\\
&=np_{2}+(-1)^np_{2+n}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1)^j\binom {n+1}{j+1}p_{2+j}\\
&=-p_{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k}p_{1+k}
\end{align}$$

---

(This section is broken.)

We can try generating functions:

If $$P_i(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{p_{n+i}}{n!}z^n$$

Writing:

$$\begin{align}P_i(z)&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{z^n}{k^{n+i}}\\&=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{z/n}}{n^i}\end{align}$$

We also get: $$A_i(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_{n,i}z^n/n!=e^zP_i(-z).$$

From this we get $A_i'(z)=A_i(z)-A_{i+1}(z).$ That is equivalent to (1) above.

If $c_{n,i}=nA_{n,i}$ then
$$C_i(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n,i}z^{n}/n!=zA_i'(z)=ze^z(P_i(z)-P_{i+1}(z)).$$